# Axios multiple request on interceptor

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency, axios, race-condition

I'm using the library **axios** in my react app.
I'm having a problem with the interceptor. 

My question is let say I have three requests happening concurrently and I don't have the token, the interceptor calling the `getUserRandomToken` three time, I want the interceptor will wait until I'm getting the token from the first request and then continue to the others.
P.S. the token he is with an expiration date so I also checking for it and if the expiration date is not valid I need to create a new token.

This is the interceptor:

```html
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    /*I'm getting the token from the local storage
    If there is any add it to the header for each request*/
    if (tokenExist()) {
      config.headers.common["token"] = "...";
      return config;
    }
    /*If there is no token i need to generate it
     every time create a random token, this is a axios get request*/
    getUserRandomToken()
      .then(res => {
        /*add the token to the header*/
        config.headers.common["token"] = res;
        return config;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  },
  function(error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: you can create a flag in some global context (localstorage) of which will hold a state of "generating token" and use that to tell the other request to wait until its done

Comment: you can also create a singleton object that will handle the token generations. all calls will ask the same instance for the token. that singleton will be responsible for genereting new token for first time and return it in furthur requests

Comment: @OriPrice I tried to do it with a flag but unfortunately, it didn't go well because the request for the token only happened once but the other request in the interceptor did not stop so I already got response 401(unauthorized) from them.

Answer (score 1):

How about singleton object that will handle the token generations? something similar to this:

```
const tokenGenerator ={
  getTokenPromise: null,
  token: null,
  getToken(){
    if (!this.getTokenPromise){
      this.getTokenPromise = new Promise(resolve=>{
        /*supposed to be a http request*/
        if (!this.token){
          setTimeout(()=>{
            this.token = 'generated';
            resolve(this.token);
          },0)
        }else{
          resolve(this.token);
        }
      })
    }
    return this.getTokenPromise;
  }
```

you can reference this same object from the interceptors.

see example: [JS FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/px7d9r8z/4/)
reference: [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509265/run-response-interceptor-only-once-when-multiple-api-calls/)

Comment: that seems nice, but it still doesn't solve the problem when I got multiple requests, how can I make the interceptor wait for the token on all the requests except the first request that happened?

Comment: this example does just that, it creates 3 async calls. first one reached the generate token will first complete generating it, before other calls are made. as long as you keep the same instance of tokenGenerator

Comment: I tried something similar, but my request to ask for a new token is asynchronized, so the other requests don't wait and they continue in the interceptor

Comment: Update fiddle and made get token async.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help, I update the fiddle look inside getToken I added timeout, and it doesn't work.. I thought maybe to create a queue but this is the last resort

Comment: could you share the fiddle url?

Comment: it looks better but the tokenGenerator.getToken() is no longer working, how can we make it work with the other promise?

Comment: it is now returning undefined, i think this will not work when we are using asynchronized function

Comment: I was wrong. you dont need to clear the promise. https://jsfiddle.net/94vb85c3/1/

Comment: @OriPrice you are the hero. working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can return a Promise from interceptor callback to "wait" until promise fullfiles (this will fit your case). Check out this example:

```
function axiosCall () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Axios.post(URL, {apiKey}).then((response) => {
      resolve(response.data.message);
    }).catch((error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}

instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  return axiosCall().then((tokenResponse) => {
    setWebCreds(tokenResponse);
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${tokenResponse}`;
    return Promise.resolve(config)
  }).catch(error => {
    // decide what to do if you can't get your token
  })
}, (error) => {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

More details here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/754

Answer (score 0):

Following code doing certain tasks:

1. Update Token on 401
2. Make a queue of failed requests while the token is refreshing.
3. Restore the original request after token refreshing.
4. Once the peculiar request is given 200, remove it from the queue.

**Config.js**

> ```
> import axios from 'axios';
> import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
> import { stateFunctions } from '../../src/sharedcomponent/static';
>
> const APIKit = axios.create({
>     baseURL: '',
>     timeout: 10000,
>     withCredentials: true,
> });
> const requestArray = [];
> // Interceptor for Request
> export const setClientToken = token => {
>     APIKit.interceptors.request.use(
>         async config => {
>             console.log('Interceptor calling');
>             let userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
>             userToken = JSON.parse(userToken);
>             config.headers = {
>                 'Authorization': `Bearer ${userToken}`,
>                 'Accept': 'application/json',
>                 "Content-Type": "application/json",
>                 "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
>             }
>             //   console.log('caling ' , config)
>             return config;
>         },
>         error => {
>             Promise.reject(error)
>         });
> };
>
>
> // Interceptor for Response
> APIKit.interceptors.response.use(
>     function (response) {
>         if (requestArray.length != 0) {
>             requestArray.forEach(function (x, i) {
>                 if (response.config.url == x.url) {
>                     requestArray.splice(i, 1);
>                 }
>             });
>         }
>         return response;
>     },
>     function (error) {
>         const originalRequest = error.config;
>         requestArray.push(originalRequest);
>         let reqData = "username=" + number + "&password=" + pin + "&grant_type=password" + "&AppType=2" + "&FcmToken=null";
>         // console.log('error ' , error);
>         if (error.message === "Request failed with status code 401" || error.statuscode === 401) {
>             if (!originalRequest._retry) {
>                 originalRequest._retry = true;
>                 return axios({
>                     method: 'post',
>                     url: '/api/login',
>                     data: reqData,
>                     headers: {
>                         "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
>                         "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
>                     }
>                 })
>                     .then(res => {
>                         let response = res.data;
>                         console.log('successfull Login', response)
>                         if (res.data.StatusCode == 200) {
>                             AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', JSON.stringify(response.access_token));
>                             stateFunctions.UserId = response.UserId;
>                             stateFunctions.CustomerContactID = response.CustomerContactID;
>                             let obj = {
>                                 access_token: response.access_token,
>                                 token_type: response.token_type,
>                                 expires_in: response.expires_in,
>                                 UserId: response.UserId,
>                                 CustomerContactID: response.CustomerContactID,
>                                 Mobile: response.Mobile,
>                                 StatusCode: response.StatusCode
>                             }
>                             AsyncStorage.setItem('logindetail', JSON.stringify(obj));
>                             if (requestArray.length != 0) {
>                                 requestArray.forEach(x => {
>                                     try {
>                                         console.log(x, "request Url");
>                                         x.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${response.access_token}`;
>                                         x.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
>                                         APIKit.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer${response.access_token}`;
>                                         APIKit(x)
>                                     } catch (e) {
>                                         console.log(e)
>                                     }
>                                 });
>                             }
>                             return APIKit(originalRequest);
>                         }
>                     })
>                     .catch(err => {
>                         console.log(err);
>                     });
>             }
>         }
>         return Promise.reject(error);
>     }
> );
>
> export default APIKit;
> ```

**Home.js**

> ```
> gettingToken = async () => {
>     let userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
>     userToken = JSON.parse(userToken);
>     await setClientToken(userToken);
> }
> ```